# How to reassign variable in angular9?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a func which calling in `ngDoCheck()`. That func calls several another func who reassign my variable. But variable change does only in funcs, not a global variable. `myVariable` allways 0.

```
myVariable = 0;

ngDoCheck(): any {
    const word: string = this.form.get('word').value;
    this.PasswordStrengthMeter(word, this.myVariable);
    console.log('Value: ' + this.myVariable);
  }


Mainfunc(word: string, myVariable: number): any {
    this.SecondaryFunc(word, myVariable);
    this.AnotherSecondaryFunc(word, myVariable);
    
  }
```

Comment: Return new value and in caller assign to `this.myVariable = this.SecondaryFunc`

Comment: number attributes are passed by value, not by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in the same component, why do you passing that variable to each function? just use it in that function as it's a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

The *value* of `myVariable` is being passed to `Mainfunc`, not a *reference*.

If you'd like to change the global variable, use `this.myVariable` directly from your other `SecondaryFunc` and `AnotherSecondaryFunc`.

```
myVariable = 0;

...

Mainfunc(word: string): any {
    this.SecondaryFunc(word);
    this.AnotherSecondaryFunc(word);
}

SecondaryFunc(word: string): any {
    this.myVariable = 5;
}

AnotherSecondaryFunc(word: string): any {
    this.myVariable = 6;
}
```